# Fill incomplete holes of 3D matrix with Matlab

Tags: matlab, fill

Is there a possibility to fill holes in a 3D matrix that aren't complete holes with Matlab?
I have tried imfill but obviously the incomplete holes were not detected as holes.

Thanks in advance.

e.g in 2D:

what I have

```
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

what I want:

```
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Do you want to fill our regions of the matrix which are `0`s surrounded by `1`s on all sides?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I Edited the question, hoping it is getting more clear.

Comment: How did you get a ? in a numeric matrix?

Comment: What exactly are the `?` values in MATLAB?  Are they `NaN`, `Inf` or some other values that aren't equal to 1?  Can you also show us what the MATLAB command prompt shows you for a single slice of your 3D matrix?  Specifically, if `a` is your matrix, show us what `a(:,:,1)` looks like and paste that into your post.  Right now it's very ambiguous and unclear on what the `?` are.

Comment: @Baloo, your edit confused people more than it helped. Show 2 matrices: The one you start with ... and then the one you would like to obtain (but don't put funny characters inside, it just confuses people).

Comment: I am very sorry for the confusion, I edited my question again.

Comment: I'm sorry but what you have currently could be interpreted as a hole and could be interpreted as an intentional valley in your data where it shouldn't be filled in.  `imfill` won't do the job for you because it doesn't consider that "hole" to be one.  `imfill` will only fill holes in if you flood fill a region and it can be contained within the perimeter of this potential hole.  Can you show us more examples of what you consider to be an incomplete hole and what the desired result is?  We need more examples.

Comment: @Baloo I think we need more clarification. Obviously flood fill isn't going to work because the area you want to fill with 1s is not completely enclosed. How do you tell (programatically) where to stop filling? Are the enclosed shapes always convex polygons? Can you add some sample 3D data?

Comment: Appears to belong at http://math.stachexchange.com as it's about solving a mathematical rather than technical problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use imclose. Imclose actually tries to fill "gaps", but not in the same global way as imfill -- it's only a very local filling.

```
se = strel('disk',2);
imclose(M, se)
```

This code works like a charm on the example you gave. Because the matrix is small it actually fills it, but a bigger hole would still require an imfill after the imclose.

I don't know if it will work on any sort of holes you may have in your matrix, especially for complex concave shapes. You may have to play with the structural element strel, both type and size. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it but didn't come to a result so far.

Comment: As others have said, I think what you are trying to do is not clear at all. What is a hole? You should start by defining this, mathematically, then we can help. Things you may want to check out are "convexhull", "alphashape", etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited my question to make it clearer. You can see the black area in the head, which is one slice. Obviously, there aremore black areas in othere slices since it is the trachea (second image). I want to fill the head to make a mask out of it.